# Integrity constraint violation during migration

Tags: mysql, migration, database-migration

here is the migration I am trying to run

`` alter table `user_activities` add column `notif_receiver_id` int(11), add column `is_secondary` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ``

Here is the error

`[PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7412424' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I have a table with an auto incrementing ID and when I try to migrate the table I get an error for a duplicate entry for ID 7412424... but the thing that baffles me is that there is NO record with that ID. That record was deleted prior to the migration. There are however records for ID 7412425 and 7412423... every time I try to migrate I get the same error, but with a different offending key that does NOT exist...

MySQL version 5.7.19